# Attaching resource policy to my lambda function for AWS secrets manager using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to attach a lambda permission so that AWS secrets manager can invoke my lambda function to rotate multiple secrets.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_rotate_secrets_permission" {
    statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromSecretsManager"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = "UserCredentialsRotationLambda"
    principal     = "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn    = ["secret.arn", "secret.arn2", "secret.arn3"]
}
```

The problem is source_arn is throwing an error saying "expecting a string". I'm not sure if my syntax is correct. Can you please help me with the right syntax?

Comment: Create multiple `aws_lambda_permission`s, one per secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `source_arn` argument expects a single ARN in a form of a string. You can use `for_each` to keep your code simple:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_rotate_secrets_permission" {
    for_each = toset(["secret.arn", "secret.arn2", "secret.arn3"])

    statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromSecretsManager"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = "UserCredentialsRotationLambda"
    principal     = "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn    = each.value
}
```

This will create 3 instances of the `aws_lambda_permission` resource.